# show array child dependent of the another array child member

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array, and i want to show the array values if the name of same array repeat in another array and have `true` as value

my arrays like this

```php
    $array1 = [

   array(
    'id' => 1
    'name' => internal_evidence
    'price' => 30
    'course_id' => 3
    ),

   array(
    'id' => 2
    'name' => international_evidence
    'price' => 450
    'course_id' => 3
    ),

   array(
    'id' => 3
    'name' => internal_evidence
    'price' => 10
    'course_id' => 1
    ),

   array(
    'id' => 4
    'name' => technical_evidence
    'price' => 134
    'course_id' => 3
    ),


];


  $array2 = [

    array(
    'id' => 3
    'name' => graphic
    'price' => 150
    'attr' => array(
               'internal_evidence' => 'true',
               'international_evidence' => 'false',
               'technical_evidence' => 'true'
              )
   ),

    array(
    'id' => 5
    'name' => 3dmax
    'price' => 300
    'attr' => array(

              )
   ),

    array(
    'id' => 1
    'name' => ICDL
    'price' => 480
    'attr' => array(
               'internal_evidence' => 'true',
              )
   ),


];
```

I want to access and show all `attr` members with value `true` in `array2`

Also, the `course_id` from `array1` must be the same as `id` in `array2`

Like this:

```html
<p>internal_evidence with id=1 and price=30 </p>
<p>technical_evidence with id=4 and price=134 </p>
<p>internal_evidence with id=3 and price=10 </p>
```

i tried this code but its don`t work properly

```php
        $array1ByIdAndName = array_reduce($array1, static function ($byIdAndName, $entry) {
  $byIdAndName[$entry['product_id']][$entry['e_name']] = $entry;
  return $byIdAndName;
});

$array2 = array_map(static function ($entry) use ($array1ByIdAndName) {
  $entry['total_price'] = $entry['price'];
  $entry['attr'] = array_reduce(array_keys($entry['attr']), static function ($attrs, $attrName) use ($array1ByIdAndName, &$entry) {
    if ($entry['attr'][$attrName] === 'true') {
      $attrs[] = $attrName;
      $entry['total_price'] += $array1ByIdAndName[$entry['id']][$attrName]['price'];
    }
    return $attrs;
  }, []);
  return $entry;
}, $array2);
```

you should know to i dont want to show by `id` in `array1` and `array2`. i want to show by `course_id` in `array1` in `array2` with true value in `attr` member in `array2`

Comment: show us what you've tried(code) and what doesn't work (expected vs. actual outcome), so we can help you.

Comment: I edit my question and add my code

Comment: `['attr']['internal_evidence'] == true` or `['attr']['technical_evidence'] == true`, would that be based on `['name']` from `$array1`?

Comment: yess. but i want to show this if it repeat in array child member in `array2` and have `true` value with same id

Comment: there is no `id=4` in `$array2`, yet you do present it in the result?

Comment: you should know to i dont want to show by id in `array1` and `array2`. i want to show by `course_id` in `array1` in `array2` with true value in `attr` member in `array2`

Answer (score 0):

you can just use this code

```php
$array1ByIdAndName = array_reduce($array1, static function ($byIdAndName, $entry) {
  $byIdAndName[$entry['course_id']][$entry['name']] = $entry;
  return $byIdAndName;
});

$array2 = array_map(static function ($entry) use ($array1ByIdAndName) {
  $entry['total_price'] = $entry['price'];
  $entry['attr'] = array_reduce(array_keys($entry['attr']), static function ($attrs, $attrName) use ($array1ByIdAndName, &$entry) {
    if ($entry['attr'][$attrName] === 'true') {
      $attrs[] = $attrName;
      $entry['total_price'] += $array1ByIdAndName[$entry['id']][$attrName]['price'];
        $entry[$attrName] = $array1ByIdAndName[$entry['id']][$attrName]['price'];
    }
    return $attrs;
  }, []);
  return $entry;
}, $array2);




echo '<pre>';
print_r($array2);
```